# How to create and run animation at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, runtime

I'm making a game currently and want to create and run an animation at runtime.
This is what I got so far:

```
void Start()
{
    Sprite[] sprites = upgrades.GetComponent<uprgades>().sprites;
    AnimationClip animClip = new AnimationClip();
    animClip.frameRate = 60;

    EditorCurveBinding spriteBinding = new EditorCurveBinding();
    spriteBinding.type = typeof(SpriteRenderer);
    spriteBinding.path = "";
    spriteBinding.propertyName = "m_Sprite"; 

    ObjectReferenceKeyframe[] spriteKeyFrames = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe[sprites.Length];
    for(int j = 0; j < (sprites.Length); j++)
    {
        spriteKeyFrames[j] = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe();
        spriteKeyFrames[j].time = j;
        spriteKeyFrames[j].value = sprites[j];
    }

    AnimationUtility.SetObjectReferenceCurve(animClip, spriteBinding, spriteKeyFrames);
    AnimationClipSettings animClipSett = new AnimationClipSettings();
    animClipSett.loopTime = true;

    animClip.legacy = true; //added
 
    AnimationUtility.SetAnimationClipSettings(animClip, animClipSett);
```

I don't understand everything completely cause I found this in the internet. But now I need to start the animation. So I did this:

```
    Animation anim = someGameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
    anim.clip = animClip;
    anim.Play();
}
```

But this doesnt work. I think it has something to do that I don't have any Animator / or Controller but I don't know if I have to add them how and where I should do this

Comment: Have you tried making the `AnimationClip` [`legacy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip-legacy.html) ?

Comment: I've added it (you can see where in the code above) but it doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running the animation? Is it in the update function?